# How do I set is_active_sidebar?

Tags: sidebar

I have a Page like:

```
<?php 
/* 
    Template Name: Agenda
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            My Hompagetext
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar('test'); ?>
</div><!-- .wrap -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

I have a sidebar called: sidebar-test.php

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Test Sidebar', 'rczo2' ); ?>">
    this text is displayed on the bottom but I want it in the sidebar on the right side
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

I tryed reading across the WP-documentation and found how to register a widget, but not how to include a simple script like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add:

```
<body <?php body_class('has-sidebar'); ?>>
```

to the header of my Page

Comment: Just for your understanding: `has-sidebar` has nothing to do with WordPress, or `is_active_sidebar()`. It's apparently just an HTML class that your CSS framework requires to give you the layout you want. If your _actual_ question was how to add the `has-sidebar` class so that you could get the layout you wanted, then that's the question you should have asked. As it stands this question as a textbook [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks Jacob
is_active_sidebar is definately a function in Wordpress, at least its documentd there and is related to the class has-sidebar. I did not find any match searching W3C with this terms.
I am familiar with Classes, but i did not find out why and where Wordpressthemes or Wordpress sets this class in some circumstances or does not set it. For me its a acceptable workaround. Perhaps even the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, reading your question, you are asking how to call up a widget that you've registered?  If so, in the overall sidebar template (likely, sidebar.php), at the point where you want the widget to show, if the sidebar widget is named 'sidebar-test',  add:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-test' ) ) dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-test' ); ?>
```

Comment: This works! but now the text from the widget is displayed on the bottom instead in the sidebar.
I have no has-sidebar class in the body!